# Why does my 'menu hide' code not work when I place it within my external script file?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a  `/js/common.js` file attached in the `<head>` of my webpage, and then the file for my page `/about.aspx`.

```
<script src='/js/common.js'></script>
<script src='/js/modernizr-custom.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
```

I can hear how dumb this question is, and I do apologise, but it is annoying me as to why I can not figure it out.

This code here shows and hides the navigation:

```
var didScroll;
/* more variables .. */

$(window).scroll(function (event) {
    didScroll = true;
});

setInterval(function () {
    if (didScroll) {
        hasScrolled();
        didScroll = false;
    }
}, 250);

function hasScrolled() {
    var st = $(this).scrollTop();

    /* Rest of code */
}
```

And my `common.js` file has the following structure:

```
// Declarations

var pageLoaded = false;
var fontsLoaded = false;

// Wrapper 
function wrapperWidth() {
    return parseFloat(document.getElementById("wrapper").offsetWidth);
}

// And so on.. 

//-----------------------
// jQuery Initialisation
//-----------------------

$(document).ready(function () {


    //Set variables on page load
    $(window).load(function () {
        pageLoaded = true;
        fontsLoaded = true;

    });

});
```

If I place my `js` to hide the menu on scroll within the external `.js` file `common.js`, the javascript does not work and I don't know why?

At present, I place it right before the closing `</body>` tag on each page.

I wish to be able to place my javascript in one place 1) so that it can be easily found for maintenance and 2) most importantly, to speed up load time, as the more `<script></script>` tags one has, will slow down page load.

Can someone please explain why my 'menu hide' javascript will not work when I place within my `common.js` file?

Comment: Did you check your console to see if there was any error? Alternatively check if your js code is called.

Comment: You can check if ur common.js is properly called by console.log or giving alert msg outside the any function.

Comment: And also check if u r calling JQuery min.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if you called properly your common.js and jquery min.js

Call it in below given order

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/common.js"> </script>
```

Comment: You absolute genius. Would you mind explaining what I was doing wrong? I have updated my answer to show how I was calling it. Was it simply the order in which they were called?

Comment: Thanks for the compliment, You are using JQuery in your code, you must load jquery.min.js first.

Comment: Have you ever ask yourself why you add JQuery.min.js first then you write js functions and all in same html page?